# mongorestore fails due to invalid BSONSize

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I have a script which dumps a mongodb

`mongodump --archive=$MONGODB_PATH --host $MONGODB_HOST --port $MONGODB_PORT --username $MONGODB_USER --password $MONGODB_PASS --db $MONGODB_NAME`

but when I try to restore it with

`mongorestore -d db_name backup/dump`

it fails with:

`Failed: dump_name: error restoring from backup/dump/dump_name: reading bson input: invalid BSONSize: -2120621459 bytes`

I tried `--batchSize=100` but it didn't solve the issue for me.

What's going wrong here?

> **Solution was:** `mongorestore --archive=backup/dump`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you dump with `--archive` flag you must restore with `--archive` flag as well.

Comment: Do you know how this work with the `bsondump` utility?

Comment: `bsondump` is for manually examining bson that's in `.bson` file (like after `mongodump` without archive option. The format of the archive file is not regular bson.

Comment: I tried `gzip -d -c data.gz | bsondump` without success.

Comment: Aha. There are 4 Magic bytes at the begginging. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/blob/7c66b71dc6036ef84bf3c2c93cf2e50f730853fc/archive/archive.go#L46 and so
`gzip -d -c data.gz | tail -c +5 | bsondump` show json. There is still invalid BSONSize error, but data are readable.