# Unable to restore BSON data into cosmos collection using mongorestore

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, azure-cosmosdb

I have exported data from Azure CosmosDB collection using below command,

> mongoexport -h xyz.documents.azure.com:10255 -u DB -p password -d DB
>   -c Product --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates -o backup.bson

Now im restoring it to same collection using below command,

> mongorestore -h xyz.documents.azure.com:10255 -u user1 -p password -d
>   DB -c Product --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --dir backup.bson
>   --numParallelCollections=1

However getting below error,

> Failed: xyz.Product: error restoring from backup.bson: reading bson
>   input: invalid BSONSize: 1767842427 bytes

Comment: aah.. my bad. Can you tell me what is the MongoDB version are you using?

Comment: Your issue is that you're exporting and importing with different tools. Either use `mongoexport` + `mongoimport`, or `mongodump` + `mongorestore`.

Comment: Thank for the clarification, @DavidMakogon. it worked for me.

Comment: @Ganesh - good to hear. I posted as a proper answer, so this can be closed out accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to close this question properly: The issue is that you're exporting and importing with different tools.

Either use:

- `mongoexport` + `mongoimport` (which writes and reads JSON or CSV)
- `mongodump` + `mongorestore` (which writes & reads a binary file).

You can't mix the two, and that was the root cause of your error, exporting as text and trying to import as BSON.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like possible duplicate of [mongorestore fails due to invalid BSONSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42948610/mongorestore-fails-due-to-invalid-bsonsize) . Can you check the link and try once again?

Comment: He is using mongodump to export data while im using mongoexport.

Comment: I am not a pro in this but as per my understanding Mongodump uses bson file structure and in general it also maintain the data types. In case you're using mongoexport you will lose data type of the values. That's why mongodump is more preferred if you need to import back your DB. A quick google search gave me the following link : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194370/what-is-difference-between-mongodump-and-mongoexport/194373#194373

HTH

Comment: This has nothing to do with size; the export and import tools are different. `mongorestore` only works with data from `mongodump`, not `mongoexport`, per my comment under the question. This is just a mixup of which tools are being used.